# OSM route in QGIS 2.16 can not activate

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins, installation

I tried to install the OSM route plugin with QGIS version 2.16.3 for 64-bit Windows, through Manage and Install Plugins but I get an error `Plugin installation failed`.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Can you please describe further what you mean by _it cannot be activated_? Does it crash,doesn't load or doesn't run? Or you can't find the icon (`Web > OSM route`).

Comment: I reinstall osm route Plugin and the massage is "Plugin installation failed"

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue, I use QGIS 2.16.1 for Windows 64-bit. You could try manually deleting the plugin folder in your `/.qgis2/python/plugins/` directory and then extract the plugin folder from the [repository](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/OSMroute/). You will need to restart QGIS after this.

Comment: I use QGIS 2.16.3 for Windows 64-bit. I have done all such suggestions, but still can not be active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSM Route has been able to be installed and located on the web as shown below: [image]